# Joomla ACL: Only allow access to custom component in the backend?

Tags: joomla, joomla1.7, joomla1.6, joomla2.5

I'm building a component for the backend.  I don't want the users who will access it to access ANYTHING else in the backend except for this component.

I tried following these two instructions:

http://www.aclmanager.net/blog/general/31-how-to-add-basic-acl-support-to-your-extension

http://docs.joomla.org/Developing_a_Model-View-Controller_%28MVC%29_Component_for_Joomla!1.6_-_Part_14#Describing_the_ACL

I made a new User Group with a parent of public and allow admin login (which would lock them out of everything) and then tried adding the ACL code from those links above with permissions to create and edit but I just get a blank screen (not even a logout link).  The "Debug Permissions Report" showed the correct permissions but nothing's showing up.

Any ideas?  My next step is to manually go through every component and not allow access to that new User Group but it seems like there's an easier way.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Joomla! 2.5 we regularly create "Content" only backend users that have access only to the 'com_content' component.

Going back through our steps the only thing you haven't specified is adding the new user group to a **View Access Level**. If you're using the standard sample content installed when setting up a Joomla! website you can add your new user group to the "Special" view access (although any will do).

If a new group has 'admin login' privileges it can login but without a View Access level it can't see anything.. it's a subtle difference but it's the way Joomla! works.